# Accesar a elementos de una lista de arreglos de Byte c#

Tags: c#

Hola buenas tardes estoy trabajando con el puerto serial y estoy haciendo unas pruebas con algunos emuladores, tengo una duda en como se podria accesar a los elementos de una lista la cual contiene arreglos de bytes, lo que he intentado es accesar por medio de un foreach pero me imprime System.Byte[]
alguna idea? muchas gracias, les dejo el codigo

```
 Pnl_Estado.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath.Replace(@"\bin\Debug",@"\Img\Azul.png"));
        int count = PortSerial.BytesToRead;
        byte[] ByteArray = new byte[count];
        lsDatos = new List<byte[]>();
        PortSerial.Read(ByteArray,0,count);
        lsDatos.Add(ByteArray);


        foreach (var valor in lsDatos)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(""+valor);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo qué pasa es que tienes una lista donde cada elemento de la lista es un arreglo de bytes por lo que debes tener dos **ciclos foreach anidados**:

```
foreach(var item in lsDatos)
{
   foreach(var i in item)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
   }
}
```

El primer **ciclo foreach** recorre cada elemento de la lista y el segundo **ciclo foreach** recorre el arreglo de bytes dentro de ese elemento de la lista.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias me sirvio para verificar los datos